# The cases where returning Bools as literal expressions is a better option

Tags: coding-style, language-agnostic, functions

Most people would return Bools as follows:

```
bananas(color) {
    return (color = "yellow")
}
```

and not as literal expressions; that is, not this way:

```
bananas(color) {
    if (color = "yellow")
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

However, [in the discussion at wiki.c2.com](https://wiki.c2.com/?ReturnBooleanEvaluations) Jim Perry said that if a method involve complex logic, the latter approach might be better.

> In more realistic contexts the coder might well anticipate that the `isBigger` method might eventually involve more complex logic than a simple compare of two variables.

Could you provide an example of what he talked about?

The only thing which came to my mind is something like this:

```
somefunction(...) {
    // you need to read the whole line to figure out
    // that the return value is Bool.
    // But it won't take much time (about 2 seconds, I suppose), 
    // and so I don't think this is what Jim mean.
    return (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
}
```

```
somefunction(...) {
    // you don't need to read the whole line to figure out
    // that the return value is Bool.
    if (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what Jim Perry meant, my mindreading capabilities are very restricted. Actually, I disagree to his literal statement: even in a hypothetic "more realistic context" an expression like

```
  if (<very complex boolean expression>)
       return true; 
  else 
       return false;
```

does not look simpler to me than

```
 return <very complex boolean expression>.
```

I can, however, think of examples where splitting up one huge complex boolean expression into multiple simple ones, by using multiple `if` and `return` statements will be more readable, like

```
   public boolean isBigger() {
        // compare tuples (a1,a2,a3) with (b1,b2,3) in lexicographical order

        if(a1 > b1)
            return true;
        if(a1 < b1)
            return false;
        if(a2 > b2)
            return true;
        if(a2 < b2)
            return false;
        return a3 > b3;
    }
```

looks more readable to me than

```
   return (a1 > b1) || (a1==b1 && ((a2 > b2) || (a2==b2 && a3 > b3)));
```

Comment: @JacobRaihle: thanks, I corrected it, errors in both

Answer (score 2):

He is referring to code where the reader looses context such as the if statement covering twenty lines, or in a language where logic operators operate by success (have an object)/failure (have an error) necessitating a conversion to a boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

One more aspect:

In many IDEs, it's easier to put an unconditional breakpoint on some source line than a conditional one, making the second version more debugging-friendly.

If you e.g want to debug the cases where the function returns false, it's straightforward to set a breakpoint with the second approach (on the `return false` line), but quite tricky with the first one (you'd need a conditional breakpoint accessing the return value, which you typically cannot access directly, but have to replicate the return-value expression).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your examples:

```
somefunction(...) {
    // you need to read the whole line to figure out
    // that the return value is Bool.
    // But it won't take much time (about 2 seconds, I suppose), 
    // and so I don't think this is what Jim mean.
    return (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
}
```

vs.

```
somefunction(...) {
    // you don't need to read the whole line to figure out
    // that the return value is Bool.
    if (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

The first thing to note is, that most (? at least many as in 100% of the languages I work with) languages actually declare the return
type, or your IDE somehow shows it to you. Thus, the reality looks like this:

```
bool somefunction(...) {
     // function body does not matter at all for the reader
     // to understand that the return type is bool
}
```

Regarding the code inside the functions: I don't find

```
if (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
```

any better than

```
return (var1 = "foo" && var2 = "bar" && var3 > var4)
```

Quite the contrary. It burdens me with a "complex" structure which is much harder to format in a readable way (that's what it is all about, right?) than the plain return.

Consider:

```
if (var1 = "foo"
    && var2 = "bar"
    && var3 > var4)
    return true;  // no good visual separation of if-body from expression. Or use {...}
```

vs.

```
return
    var1 = "foo"
    && var2 = "bar"
    && var3 > var4;
```

The usual professional values apply here. Write code for your reader, not for the compiler. Format in a way that supports understanding the logic. Use line breaks.

Comment: Also write code for the debugger. Depending on the features of your debugger.

Comment: Try that last one [like this](https://pastebin.com/SKB0KHN7).

Answer (score 0):

***Complex expressions***

A *complex* expression might profit from splitting in if-else-if's but then probably you rather need secundary test functions: single responsibility principle.

Especially if there would be many ifs, the test coverage of every case becomes harder, the code quality lower. This holds for a single expression too, but one would assume more general factors, not case specific terms.

So there a single return is fine.

***Temporary variables***

If temporary variables are sensible, one might have an if.

Also chained (java Stream) expressions simply form one large (boolean) expression obligatory.

```
if (map.containsKey(sought)) {
    return map.get(sought).getSignal().isDiscrete();
} else {
    return DEFAULT_SIGNAL.isContinuous();
}
```

Could become

```
return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(sought))
        .map(T::getSignal())
        .map(S::isDiscrete)
        .orElseGet(() -> DEFAULT_SIGNAL.isContinuout());
```

*(An ugly example.)*

***Effects***

And then there is a difference between *test* and *predicate* (terms in CDL jargon, not functional language). A *test* has no side effect, a *predicate* contains an (optional) action.

A *predicate* example (grammar style parsing):

```
boolean couldParseOperation() {
    if (symbol.scansOperator()) {
        ...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So that would be the case for a conditional if-statement.